# Online Exam Web Application in PHP-MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing online examination system in php-mysql. That exam will consist of multiple-choice questions; I follow these steps:

**1 ).** I add all questions & their multiple choices (4 choices for each question) in a Database Table.

**2 ).** I give **value 1** to correct answers & **value 0** to wrong answers.

**3 ).** When user click **finish** exam button, then their all answers will be added with each other. for example,

0+1+1+0+0+0+1 FOR SEVEN DIFFERENT QUESTIONS AND RESULT WILL BE LIKE THIS **3/7**

Now can anyone tell me that this process is OK for that type of application OR I need to improve it by using some other methodology. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to ask at a forum for educators.

Comment: looks good to me, i would also save the results on each test in the DB, can the user take the test multiple times?

Comment: @joschua011 no one can take same test 2 time, for this purpose i add 10 digit token to each user & through this i check who attend that test b4

Comment: I prefer you buy available online scripts in market as starting point for it. This will save you time, cost and testing efforts.

Below is one of the fine scripts that I worked it and it worked like charm. Using this as base I developed a online testing portal of over 1000 users using computer adaptive test.

http://codecanyon.net/item/online-skills-assessment/9379895

It is a good starting point for people looking to develop Online Exam System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of thoughts. Are you also going to be storing the individual answers? If not, then you won't be able to go back and see/show which answers the users picked.

Make sure, if you use this approach, that the form values for the responses aren't `0` and `1` as if people get wise to this then they may view the HTML source and cheat.

To protect against this, one way would be to assign other/random values to each form response value, then check the responses with PHP. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="apples" /> Apples<br />
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="pears" /> Pears<br />
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="oranges" /> Oranges
```

Then in your PHP code, check each answer to make sure the response is valid and increment the score appropriately. For example:

```
if ($_POST['q1'] == 'apples')
{
    $score++;
}
```

I've seen some multiple choice questionnaires penalise incorrect responses (so for example, you lose points for an invalid attempt). This can help if you want to stop people selecting random answers. Of course, for this to work you would also need to allow an 'Unsure' response (which, in your case, would result in `0`) then the incorrect responses would add a negative value.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks alot for your helpful response,  my test is in single page & no need to press next & back button but how to hide value from users in case if the go to source code

Comment: I've just updated my response with a possible way of protecting against people viewing your HTML source.

Comment: Greate, i love ur answer

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems fine, however you need to define behaviour to handle questions that were answered with wrong and correct choices.

If only one of the four possible answers for each question is correct, it seems more logical to make single choice questions (radio buttons), rather than multiple choice (checkbox groups).

Obviously this is a design question of your exam technique

Comment: thanks 4 good response, yes there is only one correct answer for every question & i'm using radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

Multiple choice tests usually have three type of answers:

- correct +1
- incorrect -1
- doesn't answer 0

So basically you have to save only the right answer on the database. I would design the tables this way:

**test**

id

name

subject

...

**questions**

id

name

correct_answer

incorrect_answers (csv?)

**test_questions**

id_test

id_question

With this approach you can design as many questionaries as you want by picking questions from the *questions* table. You can have only one field for incorrect answers separated by comma so you can add more later without the need of adding a new column to the table.

Comment: i like your idea so much, but i save only test result